# ARC Semantic Issue: No visible @interface

Tags: ios, xml, ios6

I wanted to parse a simple file using those http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/source/browse/trunk/Source/XMLSupport/?r=129 files, but when I want to use the "nodesForXPath" function it gives me an error and I can't actually figure out why?
Have a look here:

http://i45.tinypic.com/dwv0w.png

and this is the function implementation in the GDataXMLNode.m file from the Google Data API:

http://i45.tinypic.com/25krdrp.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nodesForXPath` function is defined for class `GDataXMLNode` and not for the class `GDataXMLDocument`. So, it is giving you an error.

Comment: Aah I see, thanks. But what if I need a GDataXMLDocument object and want to use the nodesForXPath on it?

Comment: Actually, looking into the header, it seems the method is declared for both classes.

Answer (score 1):

`nodesForXPath:error:` is a method that is not found by compiler, which is inside `GDataXMLDocument`

Comment: Any idea why it isn't found? :S

Comment: You could have missed to #import, or try @class className, even if it does not work, check whether that class' target is set.

Comment: and also be sure of case-mismatch

Comment: I've done all that, import is ok, checked the Target Membership and that is also correct...

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you haven't imported the GDataXMLDocument.h